# How many collections can be created in a document in firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, collections, limit

Does anyone has information about how many collections can I add in a document.

Here is my firestore structure:

**allUsers -> UserInfo -> userId -> { user info documents (multiple) }**

As it can be seen that a **single user information is a collection object** which has multiple documents.
Is this structure good or **will it cause a problem later**?

And I wanted to know if there is a limit on the number of collections inside a document. I have one user as a collection, so if later I have thousands of users, what this structure work then?

Comment: All the known limits for Firestore are listed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem of having multiple subcollections with a document on Firestore. Just to provide a quick insight and example on it, you can have up to 100 nested collections/subcollections within a document, so, you don't have to worry about number of documents - Firestore is created to work in a scalable way. You can get some examples and confirmation of using subcollections [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections).

To summarize, the main two limits that you need to lookout, regarding size of documents, are the size of a document, that can be up to 1 MB and the limitation of 100 nested collections. You can get all the details on this official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) as well.